# ajuda definindo char dentro do if em C

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando definir a variável char filename[100] dentro do if, porém da erro no compilador, mas se eu defino ela fora do if funciona de boa, alguma ajuda pls? (os #defines sao stdio.h stdlib.h time.h e locale.h)

```
void selecionarPersonagem(int opcaoPersonagem);

char tipoPersonagem[3][100] = {{"Lutador"}, {"Ninja"}, {"Apelão"}};
char tipoArma[3][100] = {{"Faca"}, {"Pistola"}, {"Socão"}};

int main()
{
    //Definição para acentos e cedilha
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int flag = 0;
    do{
        int opcaoPersonagem;
        printf("Escolha seu personagem:\n");
        printf("[1] All Might.\n");
        printf("[2] Bulma.\n");
        printf("[3] Kirito.\n");
        printf("[4] Naruto.\n");
        scanf("%i", &opcaoPersonagem);
        if(opcaoPersonagem < 1 || opcaoPersonagem > 4)
            printf("Opção inválida, tente novamente.");
        else{
        selecionarPersonagem(opcaoPersonagem);
        }
    }while(flag == 0);

    return 0;
}

void selecionarPersonagem(int opcaoPersonagem)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char c;
    if(opcaoPersonagem == 1)
        char filename[100] = "personagem1.txt"
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = fgetc(fptr);
    while(c != EOF){
        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Erro que dá no compilador:
||=== Build: Debug in projeto-mini-rpg (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\pauli.dev\c\projeto-mini-rpg\main.c||In function 'selecionarPersonagem':|
C:\Users\pauli.dev\c\projeto-mini-rpg\main.c|40|error: expected expression before 'char'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Qual é a linha 40? `FILE *fptr;`?

Comment: char filename[100] = "personagem1.txt"

Comment: Já tentou usar o abre e fecha aspas?, e faltou o ponte e virgula depois

Comment: ja tá em aspas, botei o ponto e virgula no final e continua o mesmo erro

Comment: tenta `{const char *filename = "personagem1.txt";}`

Comment: tá dando o mesmo erro ainda http://prntscr.com/jobf4k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(opcaoPersonagem == 1){
    FILE *fptr;
    char c;
    char filename[100] = "personagem1.txt";
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = fgetc(fptr);
    while(c != EOF){
        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

O erro que está apontando é outro lugar, `filename` não foi identificado em `fopen(filename, "r");`. Você têm um erro de semântica estática, a variável `filename` tem que ser declarada no mesmo escopo que está sendo utilizada. O if sem o abre e fecha chaves somente considera a primeira instrução depois.

Comment: po, funcionou mano, valeu, mas nao tem como fazer do jeito que tentei ali? pq eu tenho que repetir 4 vezes, deu 50 linhas só disso. Apesar de estar no void ainda fica muitas linhas ;-;

Comment: Isso não faz diferença para a performance, é até melhor deixar separado, pois é mais fácil de dar manutenção. Você precisaria de no minimo 500 mil linhas para tornar mais lento

Comment: valeu, to bem no basico ainda, entao nao tenho muito a ideia de ser pesado ou nao